Problem with running the emulator on Windows 10
I have recently installed the Android Studio (Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1) for some learning and unfortunately I cannot start a virtual device there in the Device Manager.
PC spec:

Windows 10 Pro 22H2 (64x)
12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-12600KF   3.70 GHz
RAM 32 Gb
GeForce RTX 4060 Ti
more than 1 Tb of free space

Virtual device and Android Studio set up:

everything is installed on same drive
Medium Phone API 35 (default, no changes in the settings)
VanillaIceCream Android 15.0 x86_64
SDK Platform Android 15.0 installed (adding this because there was an answer on the forums with that as a reason)
SDK tool Android Emulator installed (adding this because there was an answer on the forums with that as a reason)
Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator installed (adding this because there was an answer on the forums with that as a reason)

Erros in the logs (AppData/Local/Google/AndroidStudio/log - idea.log):

2024-11-20 09:58:22,744 [  25729]   WARN - Emulator: Medium Phone API 35 - Failed to save 'C:\Users\UserName\android\avd..\avd\Medium_Phone_API_35.avd\emulator-user.ini'
2024-11-20 09:58:22,746 [  25731]   WARN - Emulator: Medium Phone API 35 - Unable to write to file M:\Apps\AndroidStudio\bin.\modem_simulator\modem_nvram.json
2024-11-20 09:58:32,793 [  35778]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 35 - Process finished with exit code 0

Any ideas what is the possible reason?
I tried a couple of quick fixes (delete, add again the device, update drivers, check that key elements in the SDK settings are installed, etc.) and no progress
P.S. It is not similar to Emulator in Android Studio doesn't start because emulator almost starts but then crushes at the end and that question was posted more than 10 years ago, I doubt any possible solutions from that time can help me now. I mentioned exact error logs and I am curious if someone can understand the reason behind it and not just general "it does not start"

Have you tried to access the given locations on the filesystem yourself? Can you manually create files there? What are the security settings for the folders, do they prevent write access in some way? Have you tried removing the parent folder so that they are automatically recreated?

Hey! thank you for your comment! I tried it all but then the error was still there, but I still thought that it might be something with my "user" folder and I created new clean user on Windows and installed Android studio on it, it works fine now :)
